# How to restore the initial state of my Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle

Is there a way without reinstalling Oracle 10g from scratch to delete everything created so I can start using it without any conficts?

I would like to delete: `users & privileges, procedures,triggers and tables`.
Maybe there is a command to clean everything up?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping users privileges,procedures, triggers, and tables, etc have nothing to do with re installing 10g.

when you install oracle, you install the software that runs the database. After installing oracle you can then create n+1 databases on your system, each independent from one another.

In other words, if you wanted to drop a database, that action would have no effect on the oracle software so no re installation of 10g is required.

To drop users (plus privileges) you issue:

```
DROP USER USER_NAME CASCADE;
```

That would also drop the procedures, triggers, tables, packages, ANY OBJECT and data that particular user (schema actually) owns.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many users and objects there are, it's often just as fast or faster to drop the existing database with [DROP DATABASE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8009.htm#SQLRF01513) and re-create it using the database creation wizard. The wizard will allow you to save your creation steps in a template so that this process is very easy next time.